# Flutter FutureBuilder duplicates items inside a GridView

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-futurebuilder

It seems that the `GridView.builder` inside `FutureBuilder` duplicates each element a number of times equal to the list length.

[image]

Here is the code:

**InformationScreen:**

```
List<Reference> documentReference = [];

Widget showSavedDocument() => FutureBuilder(
    future: _futureListResult,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ListResult> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final photo = snapshot.data!.items[index].getDownloadURL();
            final photoName = snapshot.data!.items[index].name;
            final metaData = snapshot.data!.items[index].getMetadata();

            documentReference = snapshot.data!.items;

            return Column(
              children: [
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: metaData,
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<FullMetadata> snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.hasData) {
                      photoType = snapshot.data!.contentType!;
                    }
                    return Container();
                  },
                ),
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: photo,
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      final image = snapshot.data;
                      List<Document> documents = [];

                      for (int i = 0; i < documentReference.length; i++) {
                        Document document = Document(user!.uid, image!, photoName, photoType);
                        documents.add(document);
                      }

                      return DocumentGrid(documents: documents,); // <------------------------------
                    }
                    return Container();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting || !snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Loader();
      }
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Utils.showErrorMessage(snapshot.hasError.toString());
      }
      return Container();
    },
  );
```

**DocumentGrid**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_test/constant/color.dart';

import '../constant/text.dart';
import '../model/document.dart';

class DocumentGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Document> documents;

  const DocumentGrid({Key? key, required this.documents}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return buildGridView();
  }

  //****************************************************************************
  // Create GridView
  //****************************************************************************

  Widget buildGridView() => GridView.builder(
      itemCount: documents.length,
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 2,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final photo = documents[index].photo;
        final title = documents[index].title;
        final type = documents[index].type;

        return buildGridViewItem(photo, title, type);
      },
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  );

  //****************************************************************************
  // Create GridView item
  //****************************************************************************

  Widget buildGridViewItem(String photo, String? title, String type) => Container(
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    color: phoneButtonColor,
    child: Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        buildNetworkImage(photo, type),
        buildBlackOpacity(title),
      ],
    ),
  );

  //****************************************************************************
  // Create Network image
  //****************************************************************************

  Widget buildNetworkImage(String photo, String type) => Image.network(
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    photo,
    errorBuilder: (context, exception, stackTrace) {
      return type == "pdf" || type != "jpg"
          || type != "jpeg" || type != "png"
          ? Image.asset(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        "assets/images/pdf.png",
      )
          : Container(
        color: grey,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        child: const Center(
          child: Text(
            errorLoadImage,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );

  //****************************************************************************
  // Create Black opacity
  //****************************************************************************

  Widget buildBlackOpacity(String? title) => Container(
    color: Colors.black54,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      vertical: 30,
      horizontal: 20,
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              title!,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

How can I solve that, thanks in advance

Comment: can you please make a runnable version of this and upload it to github so that we can run it and debug it?

Comment: I work on private repository so I can't do that

Comment: I'm not asking for the complete app's code. all I'm asking is, please make a separate project with the minimum amount of code that we can run and debug. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**

Replacing `ListView` by `GridView`

```
Widget showSavedDocument() => FutureBuilder(
    future: _futureListResult,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ListResult> snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {

        return GridView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.items.length,
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 2,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final instructorDocument = snapshot.data!.items;

            final photo = instructorDocument[index].getDownloadURL();
            final photoName = instructorDocument[index].name;
            final metaData = instructorDocument[index].getMetadata();

            return Column(
              children: [
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: metaData,
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<FullMetadata> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      photoType = snapshot.data!.contentType!;
                    }
                    return Container();
                  },
                ),
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: photo,
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      final image = snapshot.data!;

                      return Expanded(
                          child: buildGridViewItem(image, photoName, photoType),
                      );
                    }
                    return Container();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        );
      }
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting || !snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Loader();
      }
      if(snapshot.hasError) {
        return Utils.showErrorMessage(snapshot.hasError.toString());
      }
      return Container();
    },
  );
```